How do you grep for a specific pattern between 2 lines containing another pattern
I have a notes text file that I am trying to parse via a script.
This notes file has a list of sections, each delimited by a line of equals signs.
========================

Notes here

========================

More notes

========================

I want my script to find specified text, and for each instance of that text that it finds, I want it to print the entire section, but just that section.
I have tried using grep -irnPz with (?s) in the beginning of the regex, but it doesn’t work. I have also tried sed with no luck.

You can do this with awk, not grep. You can specify that the record separator is the line of ====.

grep operates a line at a time, it can't treat multiple lines as a block.

Is the number of = always 24? Or is it just an example, and whatever line containing just = should be considered a separator?

Using Perl, something like perl -ne 'BEGIN {$/ = "=" x 24} /hello/ && print' file, changing hello to the search term. It could use some polishing, for example, printing the separator before the first match and injecting the search term via parameters.
